# $ f \in C^1 , f= o(\epsilon²),$ then $f' = o(\epsilon) $

Tags: calculus, derivatives, taylor-expansion

I am wondering if this kind of results is true :
Given a continuously differentiable function $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, assume that : $$ \sup_ {\vert x \vert \leq \epsilon }f = o(\epsilon^2) $$
Then, do we have ? $$ \sup_ {\vert x \vert \leq \epsilon }f '=o(\epsilon)$$

PS: in case $f\in C^1$, $\sup_ {\vert x \vert \leq \epsilon }f = o(\epsilon)$, I could show : $\sup_ {\vert x \vert \leq \epsilon }f' = o(1)$, yet the variant mentioned  above is a little bit more subtle!

Edit: The answer is no ! counter-example : a function can be very close to $x^3$ thus satisfy the hypothesis. However, its derivative can oscillate as crazy as possible (i.e not being $o(\epsilon)$, while being $o(1)$.

Comment: I don't think the last statement is true. Can you show us a proof?

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy yes you are right, i just fixed it , it's $o(1)$,

Comment: Could you still include your proof of the last statement, so we might be able to give you some pointers on how to modify that proof.

Comment: @Hetebrij note that proving $ \sup_{x\leq \epsilon} f'(x) = o(1) $ is equivalent to proving $f'(0)=0$.
 Then, writing : $f(\epsilon) = f(0) + f'(0)\epsilon + o(\epsilon)$, and using $ \vert f(\epsilon) \vert \leq \sup_{x\leq \epsilon} f(x) = o(\epsilon) $ one ca deduce that $$ f(0) = f'0) = 0 $$